# Subset dataframe based on levels of a factor and create new variable of quantiles conditional on variable within subset

Tags: r, dataframe, quantile

I have a data frame like so:

```
set.seed(567) 
year= as.factor(c(rep("1998", 20), rep("1999", 16)))
lepsp= c(letters[seq(from = 1, to = 20 )], c('a','b','c'),letters[seq(from =8, to = 20 )]) 
freq= rpois(36, lambda=12)
df<-data.frame(year, lepsp, freq)

df<- 
  df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-freq))
```

I would like to subset `df` by `year` and make a new column called `quant` that assigns the respective quartile to each `freq` value within the subset. The new column can assign a quantile as `probs = seq(0, 1, 0.05)`. The most important thing is that I am later able to assign categories based on the quantile such that anything below 25% is categorized as rare for example. So these can  be broad quartile designations, but the smaller the percentile increment, the more 'wiggle room' I will ave to categorize something as rare `r` or common `c`.

The output should look like:

```
df<-data.frame(df, quant= c(75,50,25,50,50,25,75,50,25,75,75,100,50,100,100,50,25,25,75,25,75,50,50,75,75,25,25,50,50,50,25,75,75,25,75,50), 
               abucat= c("c", "r", "r","r","r", "r","c","r","r", "c", "c", "c", "r","c", "c","r" , "r", "r", "c", "r", "c","r","r","c","c","r",
 "r","r","r","r","r","c","c","r","c","r"))
```

I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)

df<- 
  df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(quant = quantile(freq, probs= seq(0, 1, 0.25)))
```

Comment: How do you calculate your quant value?

Comment: First I subsetted each year `sub1998` and `sub1999` and used `quantile(sub1998$freq)` and `quantile(sub1999$freq)` such that for `sub1998`  if `freq` was less than 6 it = 25%, less than 11 but greater than 6=  50%  less than 12.25 but greater than 11= 75%  and anything greater than 12.25 = 100%

Comment: then why does the second 1998 freq 13 have a quant of 50 in your output?

Comment: shoot, I forgot to `set.seed() ` ... i think that is the issue. I will edit the post so that my output is consistent with the original df.

Comment: You could also use `dput` to post your dataframe if you're having trouble constructing it from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code to use `case_when` to make it more intuitive. You should be able to see each of the cases where the `quant` is classified and the corresponding values.  I then use `tidyr` separate to make it into 2 columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(567) 
year= as.factor(c(rep("1998", 20), rep("1999", 16)))
lepsp= c(letters[seq(from = 1, to = 20 )], c('a','b','c'),letters[seq(from =8, to = 20 )]) 
freq= rpois(36, lambda=12)
df<-data.frame(year, lepsp, freq)

df<- 
  df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-freq))

df<-data.frame(df, quant= c(75,50,25,50,50,25,75,50,25,75,75,100,50,100,100,50,25,25,75,25,75,50,50,75,75,25,25,50,50,50,25,75,75,25,75,50), 
               abucat= c("c", "r", "r","r","r", "r","c","r","r", "c", "c", "c", "r","c", "c","r" , "r", "r", "c", "r", "c","r","r","c","c","r",
                         "r","r","r","r","r","c","c","r","c","r"))

df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(qtile = list(quantile(freq))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(q = case_when(freq <= qtile[2] ~ "25,r",
                           freq > qtile[2] & freq <=qtile[3] ~"50,r",
                           freq > qtile[3] & freq <=qtile[4] ~"75,c",
                           freq > qtile[4] ~ "100,c")) %>% 
  separate(q, c("quant","abucat")) %>% 
  select(-qtile)
#  Source: local data frame [36 x 6]
#  Groups: <by row>
#  
#  # A tibble: 36 x 6
#     year  lepsp  freq  rank quant abucat
#     <fct> <fct> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
#   1 1998  a        14     3 75    c     
#   2 1998  b        13     4 50    r     
#   3 1998  c         9     7 25    r     
#   4 1998  d        12     5 50    r     
#   5 1998  e        12     5 50    r     
#   6 1998  f         9     7 25    r     
#   7 1998  g        15     2 75    c     
#   8 1998  h        12     5 50    r     
#   9 1998  i        10     6 25    r     
#  10 1998  j        15     2 75    c     
#  # ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. This is not working properly on my actual dataset for some reason. I think the issue lies with using the `max()` argument possibly. I see  in your output you got values within the 25% percentile but when using the code on my dataset values that should be 25% are designated as 50%.  I changed the argument to `mutate(quant = c(0,25,50,75,100)` which seemed to remedy that. However I have one more issue...

Comment: When I check the quantiles for a given subset, it seems that your code  is designating the `freq` value  as a given quantile only  if it exceeds the max value when it should be marked as a given quantile with respect to  the interval between the max for 25% and 50%, for example. For example, if 75% = 12 and 100%=15 then if a `freq` value is 13, it should be designated as 100%. Your code would mark it as 75% because 13 does not exceed 15. I appreciate any insight you can give. I tried `dput()` but I have too large a dataset.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Values from 0-25% are set at 25 in my example. I compare freq to each of the quantiles and if freq is larger I take that as the designated bucket. That is the reason 100 was duplicated because everything is shifted. By adding the 0 at the beginning you run into the problem you described because from your example there is no situation that would result in a 0.

Comment: But you're probably right that this is where any errors would occur. I'll check tomorrow morning to confirm my code matches your seeded example

Comment: @Danielle I updated my code to include your edits. Let me know if it's not working for you.  Hopefully `case_when` is a little more straight forward than the previous edits.